# Binning data into equal box sizes and apply OLS to each bin

Tags: python, pandas, curve-fitting, statsmodels, binning

I have a DataFrame `df1`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm

df1 = pd.DataFrame( np.random.randn(3000,1), index= pd.date_range('1/1/1990', periods=3000), columns = {"M"})
```

I would like to group elements in a box size = 10, fit them using OLS and compute `Y_t`, where `Y_t`stands for the series of straight line fits.

In other words, I would like to take the first 10 values, fit them using OLS ( Y_t = b*X_t+a_0) and obtain the values `Y_t` for these 10 values. Again do the same for the next 10 values (not a rolling window!), and so on and so forth.

**My approach**

The first issue that I faced was that I could not fit elements using `DateTime` values as predictors, so I defined a new DataFrame `df_fit` that contains two columns `A`and `B`. Column `A`contains integers from 0 to 9, and column `B`the values of `df1` in groups of 10 elements:

```
 def compute_yt(df,i,bs):

    df_fit = pd.DataFrame({"B": np.arange(1,bs+1),\
                           "A": df.reset_index().loc[i*bs:((i+1)*bs-1), "M"]})

    fit = sm.ols(formula = "A ~ B", data = df_fit).fit()
    yt = fit.params.B*df_fit["B"] + fit.params.Intercept

    return yt
```

Where `bs` is the box size (10 in this example), `i`is an index that allows to sweep over all values.

Finally,

```
 result = [compute_yt(df1,n,l) for n in np.arange(0,round(len(df1)/l)-1)]           

 result =    
      Name: B, dtype: float64, 840   -0.249590
      841   -0.249935
      842   -0.250280
      843   -0.250625
      844   -0.250970
      845   -0.251315
      846   -0.251660
      847   -0.252005
      848   -0.252350
      849   -0.252695
      Name: B, dtype: float64, 850   -0.252631
      851   -0.252408
      ...    ...
```

Where `result`is a list that should contain the values for the straight line fits.

So, my questions are the following:

1. Is there a way to run an OLS using DateTime values as predictors?
2. I would like to use the list comprehension to build a DataFrame (with the same shape as `df1`) containing the values of `y_t`. This relates to question (1) in the sense that I would like to obtain a time-series for these values.
3. Is there a more "pythonic" way to write this code? The way I have sliced the dataframe does not seem too much suitable.

Comment: on the date thing, the obvious options would just be to convert to an integer `astype(np.int64)` or use a dt accessor (e.g. `dt.year`) or combination of dt accessors.

Comment: I dunno if it's anymore pythonic than what you did, but you could  use `pd.cut` or `pd.qcut` for binning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure if this is what you wanted to do but I first added a group number and an observation number to each row of your dataframe and then pivoted it so that every row had 10 observations.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame( data={'M':np.random.randn(3000)}, index= pd.date_range('1/1/1990', periods=3000))

df1['group_num'] = np.repeat(range(300), 10)
df1['obs_num'] = np.tile(range(10), 300)

df_pivot = df1.pivot(index='group_num', columns='obs_num')
print(df_pivot.head())
```

Output

```
                  M                                                    \
obs_num           0         1         2         3         4         5   
group_num                                                               
0         -0.063775 -1.293410  0.395011 -1.224491  1.777335 -2.395643   
1         -1.111679  1.668670  1.864227 -1.555251  0.959276  0.615344   
2         -0.213891 -0.733493  0.175590  0.561410  1.359565 -1.341193   
3          0.534735 -2.154626 -1.226191 -0.309502  1.368085  0.769155   
4         -0.611289 -0.545276 -1.924381  0.383596  0.322731  0.989450   


obs_num           6         7         8         9  
group_num                                          
0         -1.461194 -0.481617 -1.101098  1.102030  
1         -0.120995 -1.046757  1.286074 -0.832990  
2          0.322485 -0.825315 -2.277746 -0.619008  
3          0.794694  0.912190 -1.006603  0.572619  
4         -1.191902  1.229913  1.105221  0.899331
```

I then wrote a function to do ordinary least squares with statsmodels - not the formula type.

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
def compute_yt(row):
    X = sm.add_constant(np.arange(10))
    fit = sm.OLS(row.values, X).fit()
    yt = fit.params[1] * row.values + fit.params[0]
    return yt
```

I then called this function over all the rows via `apply`.

```
df_pivot.apply(compute_yt, axis=1)
```

With output a predicted value for each original set of 10 values.

```
                  M                                                    \
obs_num           0         1         2         3         4         5   
group_num                                                               
0         -0.063775 -1.293410  0.395011 -1.224491  1.777335 -2.395643   
1         -1.111679  1.668670  1.864227 -1.555251  0.959276  0.615344   
2         -0.213891 -0.733493  0.175590  0.561410  1.359565 -1.341193   
3          0.534735 -2.154626 -1.226191 -0.309502  1.368085  0.769155   
4         -0.611289 -0.545276 -1.924381  0.383596  0.322731  0.989450   


obs_num           6         7         8         9  
group_num                                          
0         -1.461194 -0.481617 -1.101098  1.102030  
1         -0.120995 -1.046757  1.286074 -0.832990  
2          0.322485 -0.825315 -2.277746 -0.619008  
3          0.794694  0.912190 -1.006603  0.572619  
4         -1.191902  1.229913  1.105221  0.899331
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. This is definitely much better than what I did